# Visa for my South Africa husband

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, south-african-citizens

I'm a Romanian Citizen. I'm married with a South African man since 2002. We want to move to U.K. in Jan  2018 with our 3 children. What are his requirements to join us to Uk? Can he get a job while is in UK? Can he apply for permanent residency?

Comment: If the linked question doesn't help you answer your question, you can edit your question to make it more specific, ask a new question, or respond to this comment.  But do be certain to follow the developments relating to Brexit. Unless you have a well paid job in the UK, you may have to struggle a bit with the bureaucracy to remain.

Comment: I don't think this is an exact duplicate of the other question, as that question deals with EU citizens, whereas this question is about a non-EU citizen. I know Brexit and all that, but at the moment they are very different questions.

Comment: Romania is part of the EU (but outside Schengen, like the UK), so the two questions are very similar

Comment: Im actually asking about my husband ,he is a south African citizen.our kids 2out of 3 have dual citizenship.our baby 4years old we didn't do her papers as yet. She will go with me to uk in August. I want to know if they come in January to join me. Can he apply for EEA VISA?what will his changes be ?

Comment: @ScottEarle both questions are about a couple in which one spouse is an EU citizen and the other is not.

Comment: Poland is in the EU though

Comment: @ScottEarle so is Romania. In the other question, the spouse has a Polish residence permit, which means he is not an EU citizen.  In this case, we know the spouse is South African. So there's another difference: in the other case, the couple already lives elsewhere in the EU, and here they do not.  That doesn't affect eligibility for an EEA family permit, however.

Comment: The EEA family permit is for non-EEA family members of EEA nationals, which describes your husband. Your 4 year old is almost certainly already also a dual citizen despite your not having done her papers yet. The chances of getting the EEA family permit for your husband should be quite good. Your children will need Romanian passports.